# How can i log Squid Logs?

Tags: http, proxy, squid

I am using squid for the very first time , actually i am forwarding from privoxy to squid and then to server.
I could able to see privoxy logs when i hit a request not the Squid log.
I have checked in access.log but no luck.
Can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have configured Squid otherwise, all requests (whether successful or not) will be written to the access.log file after completion.  In the case of a successful request, this happens almost immediately, but an *unsuccessful* request might take up to 30 seconds to appear in the log.  Are you waiting long enough for this to happen before checking the file?

Assuming you're running on Linux, perhaps you could send some requests through the proxy using a tool like wget, then check the log.  This will confirm that logging is actually working.  Use this syntax:

```
http_proxy=http://localhost:3128/ wget www.google.com --debug
```

Prepending the "http_proxy=" at the start of the command tells wget to use a proxy listening at localhost on port 3128.  What does wget show you?  Does Squid write anything to the access.log file?  If so, that would seem to indicate your proxy is logging fine, but privoxy isn't sending anything to it.

Another thing you could try is to run a packet capture on the TCP port you expect privoxy to send traffic to Squid over.  I don't know how you configure privoxy, but I'm assuming the sequence goes something like this:

> Client > Privoxy > Squid > Server

In that case, lets say privoxy connects to Squid on localhost over TCP port 3128.  You could run a packet capture to see if privoxy is even connecting to Squid, like this:

```
tcpdump -i localhost port 3128 -vv
```

Or, if you see packets being transferred but want to know what's inside them, then the excellent [tcpflow](https://github.com/simsong/tcpflow) is your friend:

```
tcpflow -c -i localhost port 3128
```

If you edit your question to provide more context, it might be possible to provide a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following configuration i have added and i could see the logs now.

```
access_log /var/log/squid/access.log squid
access_log syslog:daemon.debug squid
```